# What's the image of $(a, b)$ under a typical $f$: $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

This question is about "typical" or "generic" functions $f$: $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where I leave the two terms undefined, but they are meant to be in the style of "A generic continuous function is nowhere differentiable" or "A generic differentiable function is nowhere monotonic."

Rather tautologically, if $x_1>x_0$, for a generic $f$ there is no relation whatsoever between $f(x_0)$ and $f(x_1)$, and the pair $f(x_0)$, $f(x_1)$ has nothing to say about the image of $(x_0, x_1)$ under $f$.

It seems to me that the image of any $(a, b)$ under a generic $f$ should be at least dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but I cannot think of a satisfactory argument. I'm also wondering about questions like: Does $\mathbb{R}\backslash f((a, b))$ have measure zero? Is a "generic" value of $f$ attained infinitely/uncountably/continuum-many times? What else can be said about $f((a, b))$?

**OK, this is an attempt to formalize the question: Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all $f$: $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the topology of pointwise convergence. Let $U\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all $f$ s.t. for every $a<b$ we have that $f((a, b))$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Does $U$ contain a subset, which is both open in $\mathcal{F} $and dense in $\mathcal{F}$?**

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by a 'typical'  function?

Comment: In general, the image of $f$ can be *any* non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$. So you really need to define "typical." Math is pointless without definitions.

Comment: Whatever a generic function is, it seems that $(a,b)$ maps to a generic subset of continuum cardinality ...

Comment: In an universe with choice (such that non-measurable sets exist), I wouldn't expect a "generic" $\mathbb R\setminus f((a,b))$ to be measurable at all.

Comment: For the boldface edit: $U$ has empty interior (every real function can be approximated uniformly by functions with nowhere dense image). The only subset of $U$ that is open in $\mathcal F$ is $\varnothing$, which is obviously not dense. Are you asking about subsets that are open in $U$ with the subspace topology? In that case $U$ itself seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the remark with choice. My question is just as stated in boldface. I can see why $\emptyset$ is the only open in $\mathcal{F}$ subset of $U$ in the topology of uniform convergence on $\mathcal{F}$, but how do you get this result in the topology of pointwise convergence?

Comment: @Mathgemini: A sequence that converges uniformly also converges pointwise, so every elements in $U$ can be approximated _pointwise_ by elements outside $U$.

Comment: Yes, of course, got it. If you post your answer below, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathcal F\setminus U$ is dense in $\mathcal F$ because every $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ can be approximated pointwise (and even uniformly) by functions with nowhere dense image:

$$f_n(x) = \frac1n \lfloor nf(x) \rfloor$$

Therefore the only subset of $U$ that is open in $\mathcal F$ is $\varnothing$, which is obviously not dense.

---

Just for completeness, $U$ is also dense in $\mathcal F$. To approximate any $f$ pointwise from $U$, take
$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \tan k & \text{if }x=(2m+1)/2^k\text{ for some }m\in\mathbb Z\text{ and }k>n \\ f(x) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
(note that $\{\tan k\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$).